# JQUERY animate Delay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using JQUERY animate to show a banner at the top of the page, which is a DIV that is set to top -60 to hide it. I'm using the following JS call to show the div:

```
// Animation
$('#message-dock').animate({
    top: 0
}, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

What I can't figure out is for some reason there is an unwanted delay before I start seeing the div and I can't figure out why? Any Ideas?

Comment: unwanted delay? where time-0 is ?? can you give more context? is this animation effect supposed to occur in response to an event? after an ajax call? or once the page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set the css of the div to `display:none;` and then use `$("#message-dock").show('slow');` when you want to show it? Works without 'slow', or with 'fast' too.